# Calculate the voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, circuit-analysis, series

can somebody help me calculate the voltage in this circuit (V1, V2)? The second power source messes everything up for me.[image]

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry, -1. Because EE.SE is not a homework-help-center.

Comment: @Rohat: Don't be sorry.  You're not the one who dumped inappropriate stuff here.

Answer (score 3):

I've redrawn the graphic in order to make it easier to talk about, and if you look at the problem a little more closely you'll see that since there's 50 volts applied to one end of the string and 30 volts to the other, there's a **difference** of 20 volts across the string, which is what's doing the work.

Since R1, R2, and R3 are in series, the current through each of them will be the same and you can use Ohm's law to find that current.

Then, once you have that, you can use Ohm's law again in order to determine the voltage dropped across R3; V2.

V1 is a little trickier, but notice that one end of R4 isn't connected to anything - so no current can flow - making the voltage dropped across R4 equal to ???

[image]

Comment: Hey @EMfields, which program are you using?

Comment: @JRB: LTspice and Paint